how can I auto number quantikz
I want quantikz to be able to number automatically,like this:

which I currently use align
   \documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{quantikz}

\crefname{quantikz}{quantum circuit}{quantum circuit}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \begin{quantikz}\label{circle1}
        \lstick{$\ket{x}$}&\gate[2]{U_f}&\rstick{$\ket{x}$} \\
        \lstick{$\ket{y}$}&& \rstick{$\ket{y \oplus f(x)}$} 
    \end{quantikz}
\end{align}

according to \cref{circle1}
\end{document}

However, this will cause problems with cleveref's customization, thus ignoring the custom \crefname{quantikz}{quantum circuit}{quantum circuit}
What I want is a quantum circuit (1), but putting an aligen on the outside to implement automatic numbering will cause the cref to display (1) equation after it


Welcome. // Can you please add a sketch illustrating what you want? // Your code can‘t compile, as it misses important lines. Please try your self and add, what’s needed. Thank you

Thank you very much. I have re-edited the question

You want images numbered like equations?  Usually images are numbered using captions. (see newfloat).

But this quantikz environment doesn't seem to be the same as normal images, the images made by this environment are not numbered by default, and normal images are automatically displayed [x.x imagecaption].

This illustrates how to use newfloat to create float type Quantikz.  Using the caption package you can even make the caption look like an equation number.
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{quantikz}

\crefname{Quantikz}{quantum circuit}{quantum circuit}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=qua, listname={List of Quantum Circuits}, placement=ht] {Quantikz}

\begin{document}
\listofQuantikz

\begin{Quantikz}
    \centering
    \begin{quantikz}
        \lstick{$\ket{x}$}&\gate[2]{U_f}&\rstick{$\ket{x}$} \\
        \lstick{$\ket{y}$}&& \rstick{$\ket{y \oplus f(x)}$} 
    \end{quantikz}
    \caption{Text is optional}\label{circle1}
\end{Quantikz}

\begin{Quantikz}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.8\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{quantikz}
        \lstick{$\ket{x}$}&\gate[2]{U_f}&\rstick{$\ket{x}$} \\
        \lstick{$\ket{y}$}&& \rstick{$\ket{y \oplus f(x)}$} 
    \end{quantikz}
  \end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth-\columnsep}
    \caption[``Short'' caption]{}\label{circle2}
  \end{minipage}\llap{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}% show baseline
\end{Quantikz}

according to \cref{circle1}
\end{document}


A good method, thank you!
